# Is it possible customize Hasura mutation/query Error messages?

Tags: hasura, graphql-mutation

```
 mutation insert {
  insert_ArticleType(objects: {id: 10, name: "test", spaceId: 10, creationDate: ""}) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

When I run this query with x-hasura-role equals "reader-space"(here the "reader-space" role not configured with insert table permission) I get an error that is given below,

```
 {
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$",
        "code": "validation-failed"
      },
      "message": "no mutations exist"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is, is it possible to configure this error message? Because here, the role don't have the permission to do mutation. So I want to retrieve a more meaningfull message from mutation. Is it possible?

Comment: I am struggling with Hasura errors as well and I don't find much documentation about it.